# how to show textfield at the bottom of the screen, when you click the tab in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, frontend

In my case I have two tabs, so I want to show up the text field when the user clicks the second tab (It should look like that) [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use `bottomSheet` parameter of `Scaffold` like this

```
Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      bottomSheet: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - 120,
            height: 45,
            child: TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                isDense: true,
                enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
                focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('press'),
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: Container(),
    );
```

you can hide and show this `bottomSheet` widget base on click of the tab

Comment: thank you so much, but can I ask, where should I put my gesture detector in the tab!?

Comment: And what If I don't have Scaffold in my page

Comment: You can find the current index of the tab bar by using TabController or you will find onTap method to get index,  you do not need gesture detector for this

Comment: If you're not using scaffold then you have to go with quite complex UI with Column and sub column in it

Answer (score 0):

in second tab you should use `Column()` widget and apply `mainAxixAlignment:MainAxisAlignment.end`

or You could do something like below code,

```
Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Header(),//optional if you have anything show above messages 
            Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                reverse: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                child: Column(
                  children: messages, //here is the messaging part
                ), //
              ),
            ),
            Bottom(),//here the key board part goes
          ],)
```

in this code we wrap message with expanded and thus it will occupy all the space avilable and push to bottom, and `spacebetween` will push to bottom even if `expanded` uses less space then screen.